# Isolate Facebook URL user ID from the URL with python regex

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

okay i found this regex from Stack overflow, which can isolate the URL and ID, but when ever i tried to use it in app engine (py) an error popup saying "nothing to repeat, i know theres a bug in Python regarding this regex repeating, can anyone fix this? tx

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

sample code

```
#   patt = '(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?'
#   tst = self.request.get("form_fbURL")
#   m=re.match(patt,tst)
```

im not a good python programmer anyway :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook profile URL regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205652/facebook-profile-url-regular-expression)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `urlparse` module to parse url.
The `urlparse` module is renamed to `urllib.parse` in `Python 3.0`.

```
$ python
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('http://www.facebook.com/hello/world.php?id=789')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.facebook.com', path='/hello/world.php', params='', query='id=789', fragment='')
```

Comment: urlparse is in Python 2, too - it's been around for a long time.

Comment: Yes, absolutely no reason to use a regex here. But note that in Python2 - which you will be using on AppEngine - it's in a standalone `urlparse` module.

Comment: but i think im using python 2.7 with appengine

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern instead:

```
patt = '(?:http(|s):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-])*'
```